# How to make wmic uninstall command take Y (yes) as a default input prompt

Tags: windows, uninstallation, wmic

I'm using the uninstall command in wmic to uninstall a program. **product where name=prg_name call uninstall**

When its executed it prompts the user to press 'Y/N'. I would like to automate it so that it takes 'Y' as default always.
Could you please give the exact command to do just that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the /nointeractive switch.

Comment: Thank you!. I used /INTERACTIVE:OFF switch

Comment: @Sudhakar I had to use `/nointeractive` on win2012; the `/INTERACTIVE:OFF` you suggest did not work.